# Injection attacks on a ASP FileUpload Control

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-upload, checkmarx, secure-coding

I'm using Checkmarx that scans source code and identifies security vulnerabilities within the code like SQL Injection, XSS etc..

I can't get rid off a vulnerability checkmarx detects on a ASP `FileUpload` control.
Here is an example of the vulnerability detected:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuXlsWorkflow" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<%$ Resources:Message,ERR_FORMAT%>" ValidationExpression="^([a-zA-Z]|\x20|\x2E|:|\\|[0-9])*\.(xls|xlsx)$" ControlToValidate="fuXlsWorkflow" />
```

Aspx.vb:

```
Dim fullFileName As String = AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(fuXlsWorkflow.FileName, False)
```

Even when using the HtmlEncode function, checkmarx detects a vulnerability on `fuXlsWorkflow.FileName`

> The attacker can inject the connection string via user input,
> filename, which is retrieved by the application in the btnImport_Click
> method, at line 114 of...

I also tried to do something like this:

```
Dim invalids As Char() = System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()
Dim newName = String.Join("_", fuXlsWorkflow.FileName.Split(invalids, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).TrimEnd("."c)
xlsFileTempPath = Env.TempFolder & " " & AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(newName, False)
```

Without any success.
Does anyone know how to get rid off this warning ?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If I was you, before going to blindly down the route of trying to fix the problem I would actually try it.  What happens if you try to feed in things like connection strings or sql injections.  Save yourself the headaches of fixing problems that don't actually exist

Comment: @Slrg what is the exact vulnerability that Checkmarx has discovered? It wasn't clear in your question and there are different types of injection attacks